# how to add scrollbar to unordered list with marquee tag when mouse hovers the list?

Tags: html, css

```html
<ul>
                            <marquee  direction="up" loop height="450" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" scrollamount="4">
       <li>DA SHEN-TAIWAN-CI ROTARY LETTER RPRESS FOR LAMINATE TUBE & LABELS PRINTING</li>
                            <li>DA SHEN-TAIWAN-INTERMITTENT (SEMI ROTARY) LETTER RPRESS FOR LABELS PRINTING</li>
                            <li>CBADEN-CHINA-FLATBED HOT FOLLING & DIE CUTTING MACHINE</li>
                            <li>CBADEN-CHINA-FLEXO PRINTING MACHINE FOR LABELS</li>
                            <li>CBADEN-CHINA-ROTARY DIE CUTTING MACHINE</li>
                            <li>LABELTECH-ITALY-LABELS SLITTING & 100% LABEL INSPECTION MACHINE</li>
                            <li>NARROW WEB FLEXO MACHINE FOR LABELS, SHRINK SLEEVES & PAPER BOARD PRINTING</li>
                            <li>VIDEO PLATE MOUNTER</li>
                            <li>ANILOX & PLATE CLEANING MACHINE</li>
                            <li>DOUBLE SIDE MOUNTING TAPE</li>
                            <li>CERAMIC ANILOX ROLLER & SLEEVES</li>
                            <li>MAGNETIC CYLINDER % PRINTING CYLINDER</li>
                            <li>UV LAMPS & CURING SYSTEM</li>
                            <li>ESTERLAM-UK-SYNTHETIC PLASTIC DOCTER BLADE</li>
                            <li>SDI-USA WEB CLEANER</li>
                            <li>PACKERS-KOREA-IML DIE CUTTING MACHINE</li>
                            <li>CI FLEXO MACHINE & ROTO GRAVURE</li>
                            <li>DRY & WET LAMINATION MACHINE</li>
                            <li>Corona Treater & PLASMA TREATER</li>
                            <li>LABEL APPLICTAER MACHINE</li>
                            <li>BOPP SELF ADSHEVIE FILM</li>
                                <li>BAR COATER</li></marquee>
                        </ul>
```

```css
#products table tr td ul{
    
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 400px;
    width:300px;
    color:floralwhite;
}

#products table tr td li{
    padding:5px ;
    
}
```

i want to stop list moving when mouse is over it and also to get a scrollbar to scroll through the list items. i tried adding overflow:scroll which shows the scrollbar but i cannot scroll through whole list and list stops moving only when mouse is over list not whie its over scrollbar, and when mouse is over scrollbar list still moves .

Comment: Two things...firstly `<marquee>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used..and, secondly, even if it was still a valid element, only `li` can be direct children of a `ul`...so your HTML is invalid to start with. ***Validate!***

Comment: @Paulie_D is correct. This is a job for JavaScript, not HTML/CSS

Comment: @Paulie_D thankyou sir i have moved marquee tag around ul tag now, i can see bullets too now before it was not showing. can u please help me with the scrolling issue. i have added overflow:scroll to ul:hover css which seems to work fine but when i leave mouse from the list or as mouse goes out of the ul list area marquee starts again but this time i dont see my whole list some of them gets hidden when i scroll through the list. please help. i just want it to let people scroll through the list and stops marquee effect at same time but should also go back to normal when mouse is not over it.